# Rewriting sum using summation notation, then finding the sum

Tags: summation

I'm supposed to rewrite the sum 1,3,7,15,31...1023 using summation notation, then find the sum. I can tell the value being added begins with 2 then doubles to 4,8,etc. But I'm not sure how to write it in summation notation, I figure it's some sort of polynomial, but I don't know how I would be able to solve for that or anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the value being added is supposed to double, then the fifth term should be 31, not 25.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, and you suggest in your question text, each term is the next power of $2$ less $1$. Thus, since $1023 = 2^{10} - 1$, the sum you want is

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{10} (2^i - 1) & = \sum_{i=1}^{10} 2^i - \sum_{i=1}^{10}1 \\
& = (2^{11} - 2) - (10) \\
& = 2046 - 10 \\
& = 2036
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Note I got $\sum_{i=1}^{10} 2^i = 2^{11} - 2$ using the [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) sum of $a\left(\frac{r^n - 1}{r - 1}\right)$ where $a = 2$ is the first term, $n = 10$ is the number of terms, and $r = 2$ is the common ratio. Thus, you get $2(2^{10} - 1) = 2^{11} - 2$.

Comment: $2^{11}-2=2048-2=204\color{red}6$

Comment: @MatthewDaly Thanks for pointing it out. I've already fixed the problem.

Comment: eep, thank you for correctly identifying what the problem was....

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for point out that error. I've fixed it now.